# Oracle - Use Linked Server over a second Linked Server

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I'd like to know how to (if possible) use a database link over a second database link between Oracle Servers.

I have this scenario:

- Server A is my own server, with is linked with Server B.
- Server B is linked with Server C.
- They are all Oracle Servers, all the same version (11).
- They are connected over internet and VPN, in different countries.
- I can't create a linked server directly from Server A to Server C.

This works from Server A:

```
SELECT * from TABLE@Server_B
```

This works from Server_B:

```
SELECT * from TABLE@Server_C
```

This does not work from Server A, but is logically what I want to do:

```
select * from TABLE@Server_B@Server_C
```

I know I could create a view on Server B to the table on Server C and use it on Server A. But I also need to update some tables on the third server.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you have permission to create synonyms on server B, for all the tables on server C you need to see/modify? (Seems like a odd set-up; hopefully this is something you're *supposed* to be be doing...)

Comment: Yes, i've full permission on all servers. It worked well.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a synonym on server B that points to the remote table on server C. If the server C table was called `table_c`, then on server B you could do:

```
create synonym table_c_syn for table_c@server_c;
```

Then on server A you can do:

```
select * from table_c_syn@server_b;
```

And you can update/insert, assuming the users used for the database links have the right privileges:

```
insert into table_c_syn@server_b(cola, colb, ...) values (val1, val2, ...);
```

Comment: It worked fine for me. Thanks a lot.